# How does prayer and action affect God's plan?

Tags: prayer

Here is a scenario to explain my question.

If God planned to give you a car on your 30th birthday but you did not pray for it, will he not give it to you?

Or what if its not in his plan to give you a car on your 30th birthday and you prayed for it will he give it to you?

> Note: The above example is just to illustrate. Don't use the above
> example to answer this question.

I'm confused on how this thing work. Which is prioritized? The plan or prayer or the action?

Or maybe something like this could explain my question better.

Which of these could actually yield results based on what the bible say about prayer?

```
GODS PLAN + PRAYER + ACTION =  ?

GODS PLAN + NOT PRAYED FOR + ACTION = ?

NOT GODS PLAN + PRAYED FOR + ACTION = ?

NOT GODS PLAN + NOT PRAYED FOR + ACTION = ?

GODS PLAN + PRAYER + NO ACTION =  ?

GODS PLAN + NOT PRAYED FOR + NO ACTION = ?

NOT GODS PLAN + PRAYED FOR + NO ACTION = ?

NOT GODS PLAN + NOT PRAYED FOR + NO ACTION = ?
```

But I'm quite confused on the prayer and action thing. I'm not sure that God's plan depends on our prayer or action.

So what does really make things happen for us? Any sources from scripture that can explain this?
Some term definition for this specific question.

> Action - actual related physical work/labor
>
> Gods Plan - God's divine plan
>
> Prayer - asking things to happen through prayer

The fact is I've seen people that do not pray to the Christian God especially non-believers or believer of other faith, but still things happen for them. They become successful and able to have what they work for. It might be in sports, in studies and in life overall. Does this mean prayer is not necessary for things to happen for them? That hard work is enough? How does God's plan come into picture?

Comment: Our prayers are included in The God's plan!

Comment: There may well be aspects of prayer that you'd like covered that are not part of the scope of the earlier question, but it looks like most of the ground is the same here. If there is something specific not mentioned in the earlier question, please [edit] this one to cover just that specific instead of the general prayer mechanism and flag for a moderator to review.